# How can I input a string into a text file after a certain number of characters in perl?

Tags: perl

I have a long sql query that I am attempting to put into VBA for Excel. VBA for Excel has a limit to the amount of text that can go on a line and it seems to be about 1000 chars. What I want to do is copy the query to a text file and run it through a perl script and output to the text file with it formatted the way I need it for VBA.

I need Perl to count chars to 1000 then write (" & _) then a line break then (") then repeat the process till the end of the file. Spaces or type of char do not matter. Any help is greatly appreciated. I will check back frequently to see if anyone needs more information. THANKS!!!

Comment: I am really new to perl so far I have tried this... 

open(FILE, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "test.txt") or die "Could not open file: $!";

my ($times, $lines, $words, $chars) = (0,0,0);

my @qryedit;
if ($chars < 1000) {
    $chars += length($_);
}
print FILE '" & _\N"'
$times = $times + 1

close FILE;
print "\ntimes=$times\n";

Comment: mhatlanta: use backquotes(\`) for `code quote`, please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the text already in a string, one way to do this would be:

```
$string =~ s/(.{1000})/$1" & _\n"/sg;
print '"', $string, '"';
```

or, perhaps better:

```
my @chunks = unpack '(A1000)*', $string;
s/\"/""/g, s/\n/" & vbCrLf & _\n"/g for @chunks;  # escape special characters
print '"', join(qq(" & _\n"), @chunks), '"';
```

If you're reading the input from a file, it's also possible to do this without reading all the input into memory, by setting the [input record separator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2f):

```
{
    local $/ = \1000;  # read input in chunks of 1000 chars
    print '"';
    while ( <> ) {
        s/\"/""/g; s/\n/" & vbCrLf & _\n"/g;  # escape special characters
        print $_, qq(" & _\n");
    }
    print '"';
}
```

(Some of these methods can sometimes leave a pointless `""` on the last line — in fact, the last method will *always* do that — but I assume that shouldn't be a problem.)

Finally, note that neither of these methods will do anything to escape any special characters (like double quotes) that might appear in the input.  If your input might contain such characters, you'll need to deal with them separately.  I've marked the points where you could insert code to do that, if you need to.

**Edit:** I did some Googling, and it looks like the main characters the need to be escaped in double quoted VBA strings are double quotes (which need to be doubled) and newlines (which have no simple encoding, and need to be handled with a kluge like `" & vbCrLf & "`).    I've edited the code above to implement such escaping.
I suppose, if one wanted to be extra sure, one could also escape *all* non-printable and non-ASCII characters with something like:

```
s/([^\n -~])/sprintf '" & Chr(%d) & "', ord $1/eg
```

(Ps. The backslash in `s/\"/""/g` is there only to avoid confusing SO's syntax highlighter.)

Comment: Ok it works for output to the screen how can I get it to writ to a new file. thanks for all your help!

Comment: BTW I am using the first option.

Comment: Open the file with `open FILE, '>output.txt' or die $!;` and print to it with `print FILE '"', $string, '"';`.  Or just redirect the output of the script by running it with `perl script.pl <input.txt >output.txt`.

Comment: I don't even really need it to write to a new file. Here is what I have to destructivly write it 

open(FILE, 'test.txt') or die "Can't read file 'filename' [$!]\n";
$string = <FILE>; 
$string =~ s/(.{1000})/$1" & _\n"/sg;
print FILE '"', $string, '"';
close FILE

Comment: `s/(.{1000})/$1" & _\n"/sg;` could also be written `s/.{1000}\K/" & _\n"/sg;`

Comment: Your `local $/;` solution only works if the file only contains one line. I'm not sure if that's the case or not.

Comment: @ikegami: It does what I assume the OP wanted, which is to encode the entire input file into a single VBA string, at most 1000 chars per line. Admittedly, it probably should also escape any newlines in the input, but I'm not familiar enough with VBA syntax to tell how that should be done, so I left it for the OP to add if needed.

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner:

```
 perl -lape 's/(.{1000})(?=.)/$1" &_\n"/g;' < input > output
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! When I tried this nothing happened to the out put file.

Comment: what does "nothing happened" mean?  did it *create* the file?  was it empty?  same as the input?

Comment: Sorry, it created the out put file gave no errors and did not change the text at all they are identical

Comment: are there already newlines in the input?  if so (and you want them treated the same as any other character), change /g; to /gs;  (oh, and switch to slurp mode: change -lape to -0777 -ape)

Comment: @ysth, why do you think slurp mode is necessary?

Comment: because otherwise the substitution will be done line by line, and if all the lines are <1000 chars no change will take place

Comment: /s certainly won't help unless you slurp too

Comment: `(?=.)` is good! btw, `s/(.{1000})(?=.)/$1" &_\n"/g` can be written `s/.{1000}\K(?=.)/" &_\n"/g`

Comment: perreal, where can i find good tutorial for one-liners? i'm feel not good in it :\

Comment: @loldop, I'm no guru or anything but the Camel Book (Programming Perl - http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596004927.do) and Mastering Regular Expressions (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922570.do) are solid books :D